# Ajax request repeating everytime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have multiple ajax requests in my form for example i have add size button in my form for a product what it does when user clicks its will insert input elements for a size so my problem is 
i have sku generator on my form what it does it will generate sku for my product with color name and size if size specified the problem is ajax request repeating everytime means

js code for both fields

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_size', function() {
        let size = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../app/ajax/ajax.php",
            method: "post",
            data: {
                size: size
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                let data2 = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (data2.success !== '') {
                    $('.size_wrapper').html(data2.success);
                }
            }
        });
    });

     $(document).on("click", ".generate_sku", function() {
        let $id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        let $form = document.getElementById('product_form');
        let generateSku = $(this).val();
        let formData = new FormData($form);
        formData.append('id', $id);
        formData.append('generate_sku', generateSku);
        $.ajax({
            url: "../app/ajax/ajax.php",
            method: "post",
            data: formData,
            success: function(data3) {
                console.log(data3);
                // let data2 = $.parseJSON(data);
                // if (data2.success !== '') {
                //     $("#sku" + $id).val(data2.success);
                //     manageErrors();
                // }
                // if (data2.error !== '') {
                //     $.each(data2.error, function(index, element) {
                //         $("#product_form").find("input[name='" + index + "']").addClass("form_error");
                //         $("#product_form").find("input[name='" + index + "']").next(".error").html(element);
                //     });
                // }
            },
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
```

php code for both fields

```
    if(isset($_POST['size']))
   {
      $size = new SizeClass();

      $allSizes = $size->showAll();
      $data = "<div class='form-group'><label for='size'>Size</label> 
      <select class='form-control' id='size' name='size'><option 
      value=''>Select</option>";
     while($row = $allSizes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
     {
      $sizeName = $row['size_name'];
       $sizeId = $row['size_id'];
       $data .= "<option value='$sizeId'>$sizeName</option>";
      }

     $data .= "</select></div>";
     $data .= "<div class='form-group'><label for='size_price'>Size 
    Price</label><input type='text' class='form-control' name='size_price' 
    placeholder='If this size has different price add here' 
    id='size_price'></div>";

    echo json_encode(["success" => $data]);
  }




  if(isset($_POST['generate_sku']))
  {
  if(!empty($_POST['size']))
   {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if(!empty($_POST["color_name$id"]))
    {
        $size = new SizeClass();
        $sizeFind = $size->find($_POST['size']);
        $row = $sizeFind->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $size = str_split($row['size_name']);
        $sizeName = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
            $sizeName .= $size[$i];
        }
        $color = str_split($_POST["color_name$id"]);
        $colorName = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
            $colorName .= $color[$i];
        }
        $randomid = mt_rand(1000, 9999);

        $sku = $sizeName . "-" . $colorName . "-" . $randomid;

        echo json_encode(["success" => $sku]);
    }
    else
    {
        $error = [];
        $error["color_name$id"] = "Color name must be required";

        echo json_encode(["error" => $error]);
    }
    }
    else
   {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if(!empty($_POST["color_name$id"]))
    {
        $color = str_split($_POST["color_name$id"]);
        $colorName = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
            $colorName .= $color[$i];
        }
        $randomid = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
        $colorName .= "-" . $randomid;
        echo json_encode(["success" => $colorName]);
    }
    else
    {
        $error = [];
        $error["color_name$id"] = "Color name must be required";

        echo json_encode(["error" => $error]);
    }

    }
   }
```

expected output is for one request this is returning 2 requests dnt know why

means it is returning

```
    {"success":"<div class='form-group'><label for='size'>Size<\/label> 
    <select class='form-control' id='size' name='size'><option 
    value=''>Select<\/option><option value='1'>Xl<\/option><option 
    value='2'>Medium<\/option><option value='3'>Small<\/option><\/select> 
    <\/div><div class='form-group'><label for='size_price'>Size 
    Price<\/label><input type='text' class='form-control' name='size_price' 
    placeholder='If this size has different price add here' id='size_price'> 
    <\/div>"}{"error":{"color_name1":"Color name must be required"}}
```

expected result

```
   {"error":{"color_name1":"Color name must be required"}}
```

Debugging details are this

when i console.log(data) 
the answer is

```
    {"success":"<div class='form-group'><label for='size'>Size<\/label><select class='form-control' id='size' name='size'><option value=''>Select<\/option><option value='1'>Xl<\/option><option value='2'>Medium<\/option><option value='3'>Small<\/option><\/select><\/div><div class='form-group'><label for='size_price'>Size Price<\/label><input type='text' class='form-control' name='size_price' placeholder='If this size has different price add here' id='size_price'><\/div>"}{"error":{"color_name1":"Color name must be required"}}
```

in network tab 2 requests are there

```
  both are from same file 

  one for size 

  success: "<div class='form-group'><label for='size'>Size</label><select class='form-control' id='size' name='size'><option value=''>Select</option><option value='1'>Xl</option><option value='2'>Medium</option><option value='3'>Small</option></select></div><div class='form-group'><label for='size_price'>Size Price</label><input type='text' class='form-control' name='size_price' placeholder='If this size has different price add here' id='size_price'></div>"


  2nd for color 

  but it is repeating size request 

  {"success":"<div class='form-group'><label for='size'>Size<\/label><select class='form-control' id='size' name='size'><option value=''>Select<\/option><option value='1'>Xl<\/option><option value='2'>Medium<\/option><option value='3'>Small<\/option><\/select><\/div><div class='form-group'><label for='size_price'>Size Price<\/label><input type='text' class='form-control' name='size_price' placeholder='If this size has different price add here' id='size_price'><\/div>"}{"error":{"color_name1":"Color name must be required"}}
```

i hope now u guys get my point what i want to ask

Comment: Specific problem is not very clear and you haven't provided any debugging details. Sounds like you are loading same js code more than once. Need to do some basic debugging and provide us more clues. One place to start is in dev tools network to see if duplicate requests are made. Another is do some console logging in the event handlers

Comment: {"success":"<div class='form-group'><label for='size'>Size<\/label> 
    <select class='form-control' id='size' name='size'><option 
    value=''>Select<\/option><option value='1'>Xl<\/option><option 
    value='2'>Medium<\/option><option value='3'>Small<\/option><\/select> 
    <\/div><div class='form-group'><label for='size_price'>Size 
    Price<\/label><input type='text' class='form-control' name='size_price' 
    placeholder='If this size has different price add here' id='size_price'> 
    <\/div>"}{"error":{"color_name1":"Color name must be required"}}

Comment: console.log answer is this

Comment: i am using one file for both requests means add size request will also go to ajax.php and sku generate will also go for ajax.php

Comment: in the network tab 2 response are coming when i add size the response is {"success":"<div class='form-group'><label for='size'>Size<\/label><select class='form-control' id='size' name='size'><option value=''>Select<\/option><option value='1'>Xl<\/option><option value='2'>Medium<\/option><option value='3'>Small<\/option><\/select><\/div><div class='form-group'><label for='size_price'>Size Price<\/label><input type='text' class='form-control' name='size_price' placeholder='If this size has different price add here' id='size_price'><\/div>"}

Comment: Oh....your problem is with your php if that is result of only one request. Again...hard to really follow what you are seeing without more specific details

Comment: its not with php

Comment: Stop filling comments up with huge code blobs that are very hard to read. Better written problem statement with debugging details is what is needed

Comment: and the 2nd request of ajax.php response is {"success":"<div class='form-group'><label for='size'>Size<\/label><select class='form-control' id='size' name='size'><option value=''>Select<\/option><option value='1'>Xl<\/option><option value='2'>Medium<\/option><option value='3'>Small<\/option><\/select><\/div><div class='form-group'><label for='size_price'>Size Price<\/label><input type='text' class='form-control' name='size_price' placeholder='If this size has different price add here' id='size_price'><\/div>"}{"error":{"color_name1":"Color name must be required"}}

Comment: Problem ***is*** in php since that is not valid json. Php can only have one echo per request. Paste those responses into a json validator and you will see they fail

Comment: can u tell me how to do it?

Comment: Simplest to explain would be create separate php files. Or use different query params for each request and adjust php logic based on those params

Comment: but it is possible to work on this file bcoz i am using isset? right?

Comment: Done correctly ...yes.

Comment: So can u tell me how to achieve this correctly?

Comment: It's the last `else` that causes problem making second echo. Make 2 files...will be simpler to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the first condition "if(isset($_POST['size']))" to another one because this condition is always true.